# Skipping device labels when not unmounting correctly

Tags: mount, block-device

I noticed that when I mount a usb-drive (for example from `/dev/sdb`) and then unplug it **without unmounting it before**, the next time I plug I in, it registers as `/dev/sdc` without anything else connected.

In what way is the old device still in the system and how do I remove it so that new drives get the next free letter?

Comment: Please state your Linux distro + Kernel versions.

Answer (score 0):

> ... unplug it **without unmounting it before**, the next time I plug I in, it registers as `/dev/sdc` without anything else connected ...

This is strange, the kernel should notice the device removal. Try upgrading your kernel.

---

> In what way is the old device still in the system and how do I remove it so that new drives get the next free letter?

Try this, and report if it works:

```
sudo udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdX
```